# How to change default background color for TChromium component?

Tags: delphi, background, delphi-xe, background-color, tchromium

I use [`TChromium`](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/). I assign `AWebPageAsString` which is a static HTML page with a gray background color.

```
FBrowser := TChromium.Create(pnlHolder);
FBrowser.Visible := false;
FBrowser.Parent := TWinControl(pnlHolder);
FBrowser.Align := alClient;
FBrowser.OnBeforeBrowse := BrowserBeforeBrowse;
FBrowser.HandleNeeded;
FBrowser.FontOptions.RemoteFontsDisabled := true;
FBrowser.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString(AWebPageAsString, 'navigate:webpage');
```

When I start the application it is displayed first with white background and empty content and then my page gets displayed with gray background and actual content.

Is there a way to avoid this ? Maybe have a default background color ?

Comment: Why don't you load the page with the browser hidden and only show it when load is complete?

Comment: Possibly because that is what the Chrome engine does. When I have had the Chrome browser minimized for some time, then restore it and navigate to a different tab, it displays with an entirely white background and no content before showing the page as it was before.

Comment: "Why don't you load the page with the browser hidden and only show it when load is complete?" - tried that way with Visibility property and OnLoadEnd but still the same behavior.

Comment: Tried 1. make the browser invisible by default 2. Handled OnLoadStart and make FBrowser.Visible := true; Unfortunately the OnLoadStart does not even get fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a late answer, I know, but it's at least an interesting topic. To change default browser's background color you can use a custom stylesheet. It sounds good, but it has one big weakness - when you navigate to a page that has e.g. no stylesheet defined, your custom one will be applied. But if you know that you'll browse e.g. only your pages in a certain style, it might be even advantage, since then you can leave the style definitions defined in that default custom style.

So to create a browser with a black background (using the style described below) you can use this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  CSSHeader = 'data:text/css;charset=utf-8;base64,';
  CSSBase64 = 'Ym9keSB7YmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjpibGFjazt9';
begin
  Chromium1.UserStyleSheetLocation := CSSHeader + CSSBase64;
  Chromium1.Options.UserStyleSheetEnabled := True;
  Chromium1.ReCreateBrowser('about:blank');
end;
```

The `CSSBase64` constant used in the above code is the following stylesheet [`encoded to Base64`](http://www.base64encode.org/):

```
body {background-color:black;}
```

Comment: Works like charm. It took me just 2 years to implement it. :)