# Error while creating the TChromium in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, tchromium

I'm trying to create a DLL of TChromium to use in Inno Setup, equal to TLama made ​​with TWebBrowser, creating inno-web-browser, but I can not, I'm following the same logic of the basic procedures, but during the creation, is created window within the inno setup is strange though, was leaving the annexed print, showing the image.

**Edit**: I'm using Delphi XE2 and DCEF3.

```
procedure CreateChromium(ParentWnd: HWND; Left, Top, Width, Height: Integer);
begin
  Chromium := TChromium.Create(nil);
  Chromium.ParentWindow := ParentWnd;
  Chromium.Left := Left;
  Chromium.Top := Top;
  Chromium.Width := Width;
  Chromium.Height := Height;
  Chromium.Visible := true;
  Chromium.HandleNeeded;
end;
```

[image: Print Screen]

Comment: Which programming language in which version are you using ? And which wrapper for which version of CEF are you using ? DCEF1, DCEF3 or something else ? Could you update your question and include these information, please ? Anyway, please don't take Inno Media Player as a good InnoSetup plugin reference. It was meant to be just my proof of concept written almost in one hour with a few minor changes later on. I would design it in a different way.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE2 and DCEF3. Yeah, I understand that the inno-web-browser was something even simpler, but still loved the idea and wanted to do a version with Chromium, but I can not do, I'm doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: Is that default Chromium control background color what makes you trouble here ? I'm asking because I can't see anything wrong except that and without knowing more than just a DLL part of your project it's still just a guess (I don't know that you've changed the color of the inner page in your ISS script e.g.).

Comment: So I asked the question here, first I did not know that this was the default color, and find it strange, beyond what is giving crash when exiting the Inno Setup, in the Destroy event, I've tried various commands and no runs.

Chromium.Destroy;
Chromium.Free
Chromium := nil;

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question and include the minimal code of your library and script to reproduce.

Comment: Hello again, I managed to make the closing correctly using the command `CefShutDown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chromium control has on your screenshot its default color, so if that's your problem, let's change it to a different color. I wrote about it [`in this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12070180/960757) which was for DCEF1 but in DCEF3 you need to do similar steps. Take a look at this minimalistic code for your plugin which adds to the initialization function new `Color` parameter and shows how to set Chromium control background color:

```pascal
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.GraphUtil, Soap.EncdDecd,
  CefVCL;

procedure CreateChromium(ParentWnd: HWND; Color: TColor; Left, Top, Width,
  Height: Integer); stdcall;

implementation

var
  Chromium: TChromium;

procedure CreateChromium(ParentWnd: HWND; Color: TColor; Left, Top, Width,
  Height: Integer);
const
  CSSHeader = 'data:text/css;charset=utf-8;base64,';
begin
  Chromium := TChromium.Create(nil);
  Chromium.ParentWindow := ParentWnd;

  // here is the tricky part; you must take the constant CSS header part and
  // concatenate it with Base64 encoded CSS style string as shown here
  Chromium.UserStyleSheetLocation := CSSHeader +
    EncodeString(Format('body {background-color:%s;}',
    [ColorToWebColorStr(Color)]));
  // and after you set the style, you need to recreate the browser
  Chromium.ReCreateBrowser('about:blank');

  Chromium.Left := Left;
  Chromium.Top := Top;
  Chromium.Width := Width;
  Chromium.Height := Height;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Perfect man. Thanks :D I found it strange, not think it was the default color after the Create command. By the fact that using the command ReCreateBrowser to destroy Chromium, I need to use some special command?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean ? You must call `ReCreateBrowser` whenever you change any of the settings (also e.g. if you change something from the `Options` properties), because they are read only when the browser is created and by calling `ReCreateBrowser` you will force the browser to recreate which also re-read the modified settings.